# How to prevent css overwrite embedded React widget

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, widget, shadow-dom

I am developing a React widget where some clients embed it in their wordpress websites and many wordpress templates override my widget styles and make the components looks bad. Do you know any way to prevent this without doing a hard reset and then writing all the css with !important? I've read something about shadow dowm being useful but I'm not sure if that's really the case.

Comment: You can load the widget into an iframe. More: https://chatscope.io/blog/web-widgets-bonus-why-iframe/ If the iframe is not an option, you can use css-in-js which generates random class names

Comment: Iframe is not an option, and I'm already using css-in-js. but what it solves is preventing my styles to override clients websites but not the other way :(